# Trying to use VB to automate some queries. Running into what looks like a string issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I'm using MS Access 2003 and I'm trying to execute a few queries at once using VB. When I write out the query in SQL it works fine, but when I try to do it in VB it asks me to "Enter Parameter Value" for DEPA, then DND (which are the first few letters of a two strings I have). Here's the code:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub RemoveDupelicateDepartments()

Dim oldID As String
Dim newID As String
Dim sqlStatement As String


oldID = "DND-01"
newID = "DEPA-04"

sqlStatement = "UPDATE [Clean student table] SET [HomeDepartment]=" & newID & " WHERE [HomeDepartment]=" & oldID & ";"

DoCmd.RunSQL sqlStatement & ""

End Sub
```

It looks to me as though it's taking in the string up to the - then nothing else. I dunno, that's why I'm asking lol. What should my code look like?

Comment: Do ***NOT*** use string concatenation to build queries like that.

Comment: Ok, is there another way I could build this query?

Comment: Or is it more of a "bad practice" thing?

Comment: @Jeff - Are newId and oldId integers?

Comment: No they're strings.

The question is answered, I just am not registered yet to mark it such

Comment: It is quite difficult to use SQL injection with an Access application.

Comment: Difficult, but not impossible. The damage that can be done is usually in revealing data that should be hidden, as it's impossible to inject DML since Jet/ACE can't take multiple ;-delimited SQL commands of any kind. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512174/non-web-sql-injection for an in-depth discussion.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't realize all that. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use (') character to set start and end of value

```
sqlStatement = "UPDATE [Clean student
table] SET [HomeDepartment]='" & newID
& "' WHERE [HomeDepartment]='" & oldID
& "';"
```

Comment: Because the literal query is something like "...SET field = 'abc'..." instead of "...SET field = abc...".  If you try to run the second (unquoted) query directly in Access, you will see the same error.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! This answers all my questions (except the one Mr. Coehoorn has me wondering about now :P )

Comment: Joel's point is that you are open to executing any arbitrary data that the user supplies for your variable. He assumes a lot but he has a point. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512174/non-web-sql-injection for a lengthy discussion of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to insert quotes around the IDs.