# How to get name of the computer in VBA?

Tags: vba, environment-variables, computer-name

Is there a way to get the name of the computer in VBA?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
Dim sHostName As String

' Get Host Name / Get Computer Name

sHostName = Environ$("computername")
```

Comment: Note that Environ variables must be handled with care because they are a security risk (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366192/using-nt-login-as-part-of-sql-query-run-via-vba-in-access-2007)

Comment: @Fionnuala I disagree.  That's not a security risk with the handling of environment variables, but rather code that is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: better (security, immutability) use the more robust **`CreateObject("WScript.Network").ComputerName`** from *Nigel Heffernan's* answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108951/1915920

Answer (score 23):

You can do like this:

```
Sub Get_Environmental_Variable()

Dim sHostName As String
Dim sUserName As String

' Get Host Name / Get Computer Name    
sHostName = Environ$("computername")

' Get Current User Name    
sUserName = Environ$("username")

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you found the same website that I did :)

Answer (score 18):

Looks like I'm late to the game, but this is a common question...

This is probably the code you want.

Please note that this code is in the public domain, from Usenet, MSDN, and [the Excellerando blog](https://Excellerando.Blogspot.com).

```
Public Function ComputerName() As String
'' Returns the host name

'' Uses late-binding: bad for performance and stability, useful for 
'' code portability. The correct declaration is:

'   Dim objNetwork  As IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork
'   Set objNetwork = New IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork

    Dim objNetwork As Object
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

    ComputerName = objNetwork.ComputerName
    
    Set objNetwork = Nothing

End Function
```

You'll probably need this, too:

```
Public Function UserName(Optional WithDomain As Boolean = False) As String
'' Returns the user's network name

'' Uses late-binding: bad for performance and stability, useful for
'' code portability. The correct declaration is:

'   Dim objNetwork  As IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork
'   Set objNetwork = New IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork


    Dim objNetwork As Object
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

    If WithDomain Then
        UserName = objNetwork.UserDomain & "\" & objNetwork.UserName
    Else
        UserName = objNetwork.UserName
    End If
    
    Set objNetwork = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Question asked for the name of the computer, not the user (though that would be useful also).

Comment: +1 for using `WScript.Network` instead of `Environ()`. Note: you can do it in one line with `ComputerName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").ComputerName`

Comment: Thanks [Andre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3820271/andre) - I often use the one-line format, but StackOverflow is for explanation as well as copy-and-code samples, so I try to lay out an explanatory answer. The mutability of `Environ()` seems to be unknown to most beginner and intermediate-level developers, and this worries me: do you have a reference - a link to an authoritative explanation - I can add to my answer?

Comment: Always create and destroy objects properly. If you don't want to declare you an use `With CreateObject("WScript.Network")` then the object will be garbage collected properly after the `End With`

Answer (score 4):

A shell method to read the environmental variable for this courtesy of [devhut](https://www.devhut.net/2020/03/17/vba-get-the-computer-name/)

```
Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%")
```

---

Same source gives an API method:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    'x64 Declarations
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetComputerName Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetComputerNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
#Else
    'x32 Declaration
    Declare Function GetComputerName Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetComputerNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Sub test()

    Debug.Print ComputerName
    
End Sub

Public Function ComputerName() As String
    Dim sBuff                 As String * 255
    Dim lBuffLen              As Long
    Dim lResult               As Long
 
    lBuffLen = 255
    lResult = GetComputerName(sBuff, lBuffLen)
    If lBuffLen > 0 Then
        ComputerName = Left(sBuff, lBuffLen)
    End If
End Function
```