# MSAccess SQL Injection

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-injection

Situation:

I'm doing some penetration testing for a friend of mine and have total clearance to go postal on a demo environment. Reason  for this is because I saw a XSS-hole in his online ASP-application (error page with error as param allowing html).

He has a Access DB and because of his lack of input-validation I came upon another hole: he allows sql injection in a where-clause.

I tried some stuff from:
http://www.krazl.com/blog/?p=3

But this gave limited result:
MSysRelationships is open, but his Objects table is shielded.
' UNION SELECT 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 FROM MSysRelationships WHERE '1' = '1 <-- worked so I know the parent table has at least 9 columns. I don't know how I can exploit the relation table to get tablenames ( I can't find any structures explanation so I don't know on what to select.

Tried brute-forceing some tablenames, but to no avail.

I do not want to trash his DB, but I do want to point out the serious flaw with some backing.

Anyone has Ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512174/non-web-sql-injection

Comment: I've been developing Access apps professionally since 1996 but I would never use Jet/ACE as a back end for a web page. It's simply not designed for use in that environment and shouldn't be used there.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are two ways to proceed from here. You could try to guess table names by the type of data which is stored in them which often works ("users" usually stores the user data ...). The other method would be to generate speaking error messages in the application to see if you can fetch table or column names from there.