# Inserting values starting with zero in access database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a field called `Product_Id`(type string), which has length of 7 and starting with 0. But while inserting through VBA into a table field of type text the zeros is not getting inserted.

This is the insert query:

```
dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO tablename (PROD_NBR)VALUES (" & prodID & ");"
```

Comment: Can you post some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have fixed the error - you need to declare the value in single quotes.

The `PROD_NBR` is a string type and field in the table is text type, then the inserting variable should be declared inside single quotes then double quotes and between two & symbols:

```
dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO tablename (PROD_NBR)VALUES ('" & prodID & "');"
```

Comment: ...And left yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, what do you suggest?

Comment: Depending on how you're creating the `prodID` variable, see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764509/can-vba-in-ms-access-using-parameter-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: easy way is to just to check that prodID does not contain special characters and/or follows a specific format. Prepared statements are great when you can afford them.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to @Cherry's answer, the following method is less tedious than a parameterized query, aka prepared statement. `prodID` can safely contain quotes and other special characters.

```
    With dbs.OpenRecordset("tablename")
        .AddNew
        .Fields("PROD_NBR") = prodID
        .Update
    End With
```

Regarding the "starting with zero" part of your question, do you want PROD_NBR to always be 7 characters, padded with leading 0's? Then replace `prodID` with:

```
    Right("0000000" & prodID, 7)
```