# Syntax error on multiple join statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello, I'm getting a syntax error on this sql statement, can anyone advise thanks

```
String sql = "Select tblStudent.*,tblSchool.*,tblAgents.* " +
    "FROM tblStudent LEFT JOIN tblSchool " +
    "ON (tblStudent.schoolID = tblSchool.schoolID) " +
    "LEFT JOIN tblAgents " +
    "ON (tblStudent.agentID = tblAgents.agentID) " +
    "WHERE tblStudent.StudentID='" + studentID + "'";
```

I was hoping that I could do multiple joins

But I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: Access wants parentheses when multiple join.

Comment: but I've put parentheses in the statement.

Comment: OK, you should never use * to select all fields especially when you have a join because you are sending the same data in multiple columns and that wastes server resources. You should list the columns you need and ONLY those columns.

Comment: Inserting the StudentID like this, you are open to sql injection. Please use parameters.

Comment: Parentheses used in a wrong way. Use query designer for building the query, then copy it to VBA

Comment: Also I'd recommend to use `&` instead of `+` for string concatenation - in case of null value whole sting will be null and will generate an error. `&` works different way with null values

Comment: Ok I think I have got it working now. Someone mentioned using parameters. How would I use parameters in the above statement? Example would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For access, parenthesis with multiple joins means the following. If you have three joins, there are two left parenthesis after the from.  The last join does not have a right parenthesis.

```
String sql = "Select tblStudent.*,tblSchool.*,tblAgents.* " +
"FROM (tblStudent LEFT JOIN tblSchool " +
"ON (tblStudent.schoolID = tblSchool.schoolID)) " +
"LEFT JOIN tblAgents " +
"ON (tblStudent.agentID = tblAgents.agentID) " +
"WHERE tblStudent.StudentID='" + studentID + "'";
```

Access SQL injection has been covered in other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764509/can-vba-in-ms-access-using-parameter-to-prevent-sql-injection) .

Answer (score 0):

```
        String sql = "Select 
        tblStudent.StudentID,tblStudent.studentFirstName,"+
        tblStudent.studentLastName,tblSchool.schoolName," + 
        tblAgents.agentFirstName,tblAgents.agentLastName " +
        "FROM (tblStudent LEFT JOIN tblSchool " +
        "ON (tblStudent.schoolID = tblSchool.schoolID)) " +
        "LEFT JOIN tblAgents " +
        "ON (tblStudent.agentID = tblAgents.agentID) " +
        "WHERE tblStudent.StudentID=@studentID";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your final SQL should look like this:

```
SELECT tblStudent.*
    ,tblSchool.*
    ,tblAgents.*
FROM tblSchool
RIGHT JOIN (
    tblAgents RIGHT JOIN tblStudent ON tblAgents.agentID = tblStudent.agentID
    ) ON tblSchool.schoolID = tblStudent.schoolID
WHERE tblStudent.StudentID=111;
```

So, the VBA code for creating this SQL should be

```
Dim sql As String

sql = "SELECT tblStudent.* ,tblSchool.* ,tblAgents.* " & _
    "FROM tblSchool RIGHT JOIN (" & _
    "tblAgents RIGHT JOIN tblStudent ON tblAgents.agentID = tblStudent.agentID" & _
    ") ON tblSchool.schoolID = tblStudent.schoolID " & _
    "WHERE tblStudent.StudentID=" & studentID
```

Here I assume that `studentID` is numeric field. Also I would recommend to do not use `*` for selecting the data from more than one table, otherwise column names may be unpredictable and as mentioned in comments, it will require additional resources, which won't be used.