# Changing SQL select query to VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to transition my queries into the ability to select data for a mail merge using VBA.  Right now I have a query built in access that uses two parameters:

```
PARAMETERS startdate DateTime, enddate DateTime;
```

and i basically want to recreate that query at run time to populate letters.

```
date1 = InputBox("Please enter the start date, e.g. 5/28", "Please enter the start date")
date2 = InputBox("Please enter the end date, e.g. 6/28", "Please enter the end date")   

date1 = date1 & "/" & thisYear
date2 = date2 & "/" & thisYear


sqlstatement:="SELECT * FROM [Customer Data] WHERE [Customer Data].[Status]='Complete' AND [Customer Data].[CompletedBy] = '" & userID & "' AND [Customer Data].[Date Completed] Between " & date1 & " And " & date2 & ";"
```

There is something inherently wrong with my "between date1 and date2" part, if I remove that part of the statement, the query works fine, but i will require the ability to specify a date range.  Right now it is telling me that no data was found.  What am I doing wrong with that part?

Comment: Please visit [Bobby Tables - a web site dedicated to educating people about SQL Injection vulnerabilities.](http://bobby-tables.com/) - you have one that should be corrected.  Unfortunately that site doesn't address passing parms in Access, but the issue remains.

Comment: @DanPichelman, I don't think Bobby Tables applies to an Access engine.

Comment: @SableFoste - I looked it up.  Access is less vulnerable to Sql Injection than others, but there are still some issues.  See also [Non-web SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/512174/427192) and [MS Access Sql Injection](http://nibblesec.org/files/MSAccessSQLi/MSAccessSQLi.html).

Comment: @DanPichelman considering I inherited a database where nothing is locked down, sql injections are the least worry right now.  However, I will take this into consideration at redesign, thanks for the links

Comment: @DanPichelman I actually have a question about this too:  Is a mail merge susceptible to an SQL injection attack?

Comment: I don't know - that might be a good question to post on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"' AND [Customer Data].[Date Completed] Between #" & date1 & "# And #" & date2 & "# ;"`

Just as you are using apostrophe to surround the string data, the date values should be enclosed with `#`. Post your comments, if this doesn't help.